# How to split array where objects are seperated from values using a semi colon? in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

The following is an output given by a JSON for a API Query, It's an array but suppose I want the value of specific of an like a object "Mobs_killed.amount" in this case, which should return 14.

The following is what I've tried

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    Kills: '|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Players_Killed.amount:4|',
    Deaths: '|Deaths_By_Suicide.amount:37||Deaths_By_Mobs.amount:2||Deaths_By_Player.amount:17|'
  }
]
```

This is what I've tried

```js
            cQuery = `SELECT Kills,Deaths FROM \`us\` WHERE uuid =`+JSON.stringify(id);
            con.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                con.query(cQuery, function (err, object, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                let resulty = JSON.stringify(object)
                let cArr = resulty.split(',');
                cArr = resulty.split('|');

                    var result = resulty.split(/,(?=\w+:)/);
                    console.log(result)
```

But that's of no use, my output looks something like

```
[
  '[{"Kills":"|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Players_Killed.amount:4|","Deaths":"|Deaths_By_Suicide.amount:37||Deaths_By_Mobs.amount:2||Deaths_By_Player.amount:17|"}]'
]
```

If I'm unable to split arrays is there a way I can just pick the "value" of the "object"?

Comment: 1. Why are you splitting a stringified object instead of iterating over the object? 2. Your object is not valid JS. 3. We do not need to see the cQuery part, only the parsing part

Answer (score 0):

It is likely not returning your result in the format you showed since that is invalid JS

Perhaps this:

```js
const data = {
  RowDataPacket : {
    Kills: '|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Players_Killed.amount:4|',
    Deaths: '|Deaths_By_Suicide.amount:37||Deaths_By_Mobs.amount:2||Deaths_By_Player.amount:17|'
  }
}

const obj = {}
Object.entries(data.RowDataPacket).forEach(([key,val]) => val.slice(1,-1).split("||").reduce((acc,item) => {
  const [reason,count] = item.split(":");
  (acc[key] = acc[key] ? acc[key] : {})[reason]=count;
  return acc;
},obj))

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.Kills["Animals_Killed.amount"])
```

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like mainly you are trying to split the string into objects. Here is one way to do that.

```
const a = '|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Players_Killed.amount:4|'
a.slice(1, a.length - 1)
 .split('||')
    .map( str => {
        const strArray = str.split(":");
        const strObj = {}
        strObj[strArray[0]] = strArray[1]
        return strObj;
 }) // [{Mobs_Killed.amount: "14"},{Animals_Killed.amount: "1"},{Players_Killed.amount: "4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to convert a string to an object. The function takes the first argument as a string like

```
"| Mobs_Killed.amount: 14 || Animals_Killed.amount: 1 || Players_Killed.amount: 4 |"
```

and returns the object.

```js
function convertStringToObject(str) {
  var resultObj = {};
  var strParts = str.split('|');
  for (var i = 0; i < strParts.length; i++) {
    if (strParts[i].length === 0) continue;
    var posOfcolon = strParts[i].indexOf(':');
    if (posOfcolon === -1) continue;
    var path = strParts[i].slice(0, posOfcolon);
    var pathParts = path.split('.');
    var value = strParts[i].slice(posOfcolon + 1);
    var targetObject = resultObj;
    if (pathParts.length === 0) continue;
    if (pathParts.length === 1) {
      targetObject[pathParts[0]] = value;
      continue;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < pathParts.length; j++) {
      var prt = pathParts[j];
      if (j === (pathParts.length - 1)) { // last part
        targetObject[prt] = value;
        continue;
      }
      if (!(prt in targetObject)) {
        targetObject[prt] = {};
      }
      targetObject = targetObject[prt];
    }
  }
  return resultObj;
};

var str1 = '|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Players_Killed.amount:4|';
var str2 = '|Mobs_Killed.amount:14||Mobs_Killed.damage:189||Animals_Killed.amount:1||Animals_Killed.damage:984||Players_Killed.amount:4||Players_Killed.damage:791|';

console.log(convertStringToObject(str1));
console.log(convertStringToObject(str2));
```